# Make Mysql Query Case Insentive

Tags: php, mysql, case-insensitive

Is it possible to make the following query string case insensitive?

```
SELECT SUBSTR(raw,INSTR(raw,'".$term."') - 50,350) as term,
(LENGTH(raw) - LENGTH(REPLACE(raw,'".$term."',''))) /LENGTH('".$term."') AS occur,name,title 
FROM ( 
     SELECT ( LENGTH(raw) - LENGTH(REPLACE(raw,'".$term."','')) ) / LENGTH('".$term."') AS occur, raw, consol.name,title 
     FROM consol 
     WHERE LENGTH(raw) - LENGTH(REPLACE(raw,'".$term."',''))>0 AND raw LIKE '%".$term."%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci ORDER BY occur DESC 
     ) t ";
```

The engine for the table is MyISAM and the encoding is UTF8. When i run the query from the command line it works, but when I execute it through the browser it throws the following error.

> Notice: failed Query : COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1' in

The table is encoded in UTF-8 with the collation of utf8_general_ci.  How can I ensure that a query of "small" matches small as well as Small or SMALL ?

Comment: Encoding/collation of table does not necessarily equals encoding/collation of any given column. Check if your column is indeed utf8.

Comment: Encoding for the column is UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) and the Collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: It appears that this has something to do with the LENGTH and REPLACE functions?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if the WHERE clause in the second select statement was causing the issue.  I changed this:

```
WHERE LENGTH(raw) - LENGTH(REPLACE(raw,'".$term."',''))>0 AND raw LIKE '%".$term."%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci ORDER BY occur DESC
```

To this:

```
WHERE raw LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY occur DESC
```

It appears to match all results now.  The initial query filters matches from the second query.  It looks like the WHERE condition of `LENGTH(raw) - LENGTH(REPLACE(raw,'".$term."',''))>0` was causing the issue as well as the setting of the collation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtolower()` or similar to normalize your `$term` variable prior to adding it to your query.

Comment: Malcolm, the match in the table can either be 'Small' or 'small', if the user types 'SMALL' or 'small' or 'Small' etc. it should still return the result.  There is no way to know what the data in the table will look like as this is a LONGTEXT field.